# Continuous mapping on unit ball such that $T(\Bbb x_0)=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

got a question from a course in functional analysis.

"  Let $T:\{\Bbb x\in\Bbb R: ||\Bbb x||\leq 1\}\to\Bbb R^n$ be a continuous mapping. Moreover assume that $\langle T(\Bbb x),\Bbb x\rangle>0$ for all $\Bbb x$ with $||\Bbb x||=1$. Here $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^n$ with the induced norm $||\cdot||$. Prove$^1$ that there exists a $\Bbb x_0\in\{\Bbb x\in\Bbb R: ||\Bbb x||\leq 1\}$ such that $T(\Bbb x_0)=0$.

$^1$Hint: Consider the mapping $G(\Bbb x)=\Bbb x - \epsilon T(\Bbb x)$ for some properly choosen $\epsilon>0$          "

From that hint it is very tempting to assume that what you should do is to show that $G(\Bbb x)$ has a fixed point in the unit ball. To do so I'd call for Brouwer's fixed point theorem, which states that any continuous function from a convex compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$ to itself has a fixed point.

If everything is correct so far, I need to show that '  $\Bbb x - \epsilon T(\Bbb x)$  ' is compact and convex. To show that it is compact, I should show that it is bounded and closed, and then, boundedness implies that it is also convex.

But now the first real problem appears (If everything is right so far); How can I show that it is bounded? In particular, that it is bounded such that $||G(\Bbb x)||\leq1$
, or that $G(\Bbb x)\in\{\Bbb x\in\Bbb R: ||\Bbb x||\leq 1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for your answer, Daniel!

So now for a final answer, can I simply replace every element describing $\lVert G(\mathbb{x})\rVert^2$ by those numbers ($\delta$ and $c$) and using normal calculus to solve for $\epsilon$ ?

That is we had...

$\lVert G(\mathbb{x})\rVert^2 = \lVert \mathbb{x}\rVert^2 - 2\epsilon\langle T(\mathbb{x}),\mathbb{x}\rangle + \epsilon^2 \lVert T(\mathbb{x})\rVert^2 \leqslant 1$

...and then $\lVert \mathbb{x}\rVert^2$ is replaced by $(1-\delta)^2$, $\langle T(\mathbb{x}),\mathbb{x}\rangle$ by $c$ and, since $T(\Bbb x)$ is continuous, $\|T(\Bbb x)\|^2$ can be replaced by it's maximum on the unit ball which is finite;   $sup_{\|\Bbb x\|\leq1}\{\|T(\Bbb x)\|^2\} = M< \infty$

If so, then by simple rearrangements, $\epsilon\in [0,\frac{c+\sqrt(c^2+M(1-(1-\delta)^2))}{M}]$

Seems legit?

Also, are you supposed to "tag" the one you're replying to? @Daniel Fischer

Comment: `@` replies only work in comments (and you can't `@`-mention the post owner before somebody else is involved in the communication; the post owner is automatically notified of all comments, and if you and the owner are the only people talking, it's clear who you are talking to). So much for how the site works. Now to mathematics. I wouldn't attempt to find an $\epsilon$ explicitly. All you need is to show the existence of one. Let $\lVert T(\mathbb{x})\rVert \leqslant K$ (exists, since the closed ball is compact, and $T$ continuous). For $\lVert\mathbb{x}\rVert\geqslant 1-\delta$, you have ...

Comment: $\lVert G(\mathbb{x})\rVert \leqslant 1 - 2\epsilon c + \epsilon^2K^2$. For $\epsilon \leqslant 2c/K^2$, that is $\leqslant 1$. For $\lVert\mathbb{x}\rVert \leqslant 1 - \delta$, you have $\lVert G(\mathbb{x})\rVert \leqslant \lVert\mathbb{x}\rVert + \epsilon\cdot K \leqslant 1 - \delta + \epsilon\cdot K$. For $\epsilon \leqslant \delta/K$, that is $\leqslant 1$. Well, okay, that turns out to give something explicit enough for $\epsilon$ anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> From that hint it is very tempting to assume that what you should do is to show that $G(\mathbb{x})$ has a fixed point in the unit ball.

Indeed. So you want to show that - for suitably chosen $\epsilon > 0$ - $G$ maps the unit ball to itself. Now, we have by assumption $\langle T(\mathbb{x}), \mathbb{x}\rangle > 0$ on the boundary of the unit ball. By compactness, there is a $c > 0$ with $\langle T(\mathbb{x}), \mathbb{x}\rangle > c$ on the boundary, and by continuity, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\langle T(\mathbb{x}), \mathbb{x}\rangle > c$ for all $\mathbb{x}$ with $\lVert \mathbb{x}\rVert \geqslant 1 - \delta$.

Now find an $\epsilon > 0$ such that

$$\lVert G(\mathbb{x})\rVert^2 = \lVert \mathbb{x}\rVert^2 - 2\epsilon\langle T(\mathbb{x}),\mathbb{x}\rangle + \epsilon^2 \lVert T(\mathbb{x})\rVert^2 \leqslant 1$$

for all $\mathbb{x}$ in the closed unit ball.